# How to get the value of TextInput before it was changed?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
<TextInput
                        id="txtDupProjectName"
                        labelText=""
                        placeholder="Name"
                        required
                        defaultValue={this.projectName + "_Copy"}
                        // invalid={this.dupProjectName === ''}
                        // invalidText="Mandatory"
                        onChange={ e => this.handleDupProjectNameChange(e) }
                    />
```

If I don't type any character inside the textInput (handleDupProjectNameChange isn't called), but need to save my change with default value inside it...

I used (based on the naswer of Jeroen Jonkman):

```
document.getElementById('txtDupProjectName').value
```

and in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {

    console.log("...............", document.getElementById('txtDupProjectName').value  )

    this.setState({
        dupProjectName: document.getElementById('txtDupProjectName').value
    })
}
```

But the problem that I have more than one component (from the same type) displayed at the same time, so the id that I'm using is not identical nad I'm getting the value of one them to all others...

I will try to use the project name in id to make it identical

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('txtDupProjectName')[0].defaultValue` ? I'm surprised your react component has that property set - on `HTMLInputElement` this property keeps the start value of the input (without you having to do anything for it). **Also note that *didn't work*  is not at all a helpful problem description!!**

Answer (score 2):

If you need to take the value before any changed will make, you need to use `onfocus` event. This is throwed every time the field is active by the user.

Comment: I used the componentDidMout hook to take the value from the textinput and set it inside a state variable instead, but your approch is also good

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a name attribute used in the input field.

Use: document.getElementById('...').. instead or add a name attribute

Comment: Didn't pay attention... my bad